# PHP File Download Issue - Can't Read

Tags: php, file, download

I have the following code for downloading files automatically
at the click of a submit button, everything seems to work fine;
the file downloads in the rigth format, right size, right name, but when I
want to open it, I get an error, the file cannot be read, what could be the
problem?

```
$file=mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
$file=$file['downloadlink'];
header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
readfile($file);
```

Comment: is the file stored with the right extension? e.g. `.docx` vs `.doc`

Comment: The only thing I see here that could be messing with your file is the transfer encoding

Comment: Yes, files are stored with the right extension.

Comment: You mean you download a file to your local system, which you claim works, and then you ask us why you cannot open the file on your system? Em... Are we meant to do magic? What about posting some details about the file? What about sharing the error message?

Comment: Is downloaded file name have extension? It must be doc or docx.

Comment: I'm testing with various file types; zip and pdf, I can open the test file before upload but when I download it via the script and try to open I get an error "...it is either not a supported filetype or because the file has been damaged..." in the case of a pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try tweaking this function from the `readfile()` comments:

```
function DownloadFile($file) { // $file = include path
    if(file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Waooh! Thanks man, I added the missing lines to my code and everything is now ok, both pdf and zip can be opened.

Answer (score 1):

I have an addition for this. If the file size is very big, it'll download empty file which we cannot open at all. That is not a problem with 'readfile' function itself. The problem is reading large files into memory. So, for preventing that kind of issues, we have to use 'ob_end_flush()' immediately before to the 'readfile' function for turning off output buffer.

Hope this tip will save someones time. :)

Comment: Just saved my day with this comment. Large file downloads were erroring out, adding `ob_end_flush()` right before `readfile()` fixed it. Thanks man!